# Can I refill 7-day Unlimited MetroCard to use as Pay-Per-Ride MetroCards after 7 days or vice versa?

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, new-york-city

A NYC MetroCard will cost $1 (as of today) each time we apply for a new card. So can we refill the "7-day Unlimited MetroCard" after it expires? For an example if I go to subway station on 8th day and tried to refill it with $11, will it be allowed?

Or else can I buy a "Pay-Per-Ride MetroCard" and then add the "7-day unlimited" ride option to "Pay-Per-Ride MetroCard" and once it get expired will I still be able to use the "Pay-Per-Ride MetroCard" card on 8th day and forward?

Is there any expiration time for these metro cards? Will I be able to use them in my next trip as well?

Comment: YES.  You can add any entitlement to a MetroCard (except Unlimited AirTrain) at the same time.  Unlimited time will be applied before any fare is deducted.

Answer (score 5):

You can add ***Time*** to a Pay Per Ride metrocard. The vending machine will prompt you to choose. You can also tell the agent to add Time to your metrocard if you're paying at a booth.

Once ***Time*** is added, the metrocard behaves as an unlimited metrocard until said time expires. After that, it will behave as a "Pay Per Ride" metrocard again. You can refill a metrocard with either ***Time*** or ***Value (money)*** as often as you'd like. Source [here](http://www.mta.info/press-release/mta-headquarters/mta-makes-metrocard-refills-easier), relevant example (copied from source) pasted below:

> For example, if you have $5 in value remaining on your MetroCard and
>   add a 7-day unlimited ride pass, the next time you use your card, it
>   will activate the unlimited rides and the $5 value will only become
>   available when the 7-day time period expires. Note again however, that
>   if a customer wants to access locations where a 30-Day pass is not
>   accepted such as express buses, PATH or AirTrain stations, the
>   appropriate fare will be deducted, as long as there is enough monetary
>   value on the card.

Metrocards usually [expire after a year](http://web.mta.info/metrocard/problems.htm#expired):

> Has your MetroCard expired?
>
> Whether Pay-Per-Ride or Unlimited Ride, every MetroCard has an
>   expiration date. The date is located at the upper left corner on the
>   back of the card. The expiration date is usually about one year from
>   the date of purchase.
>
> If your Pay-Per-Ride MetroCard expires, you have two years from the
>   expiration date to transfer any remaining money to a new card. Within
>   the first year after expiration, bring your expired card to any subway
>   station and ask the agent to make the transfer. After that time, the
>   expired MetroCard must be sent to MetroCard customer claims. Ask the
>   station agent for a postage-paid Business Reply Envelope.
>
> ```
> MetroCard Customer Claims
> 130 Livingston Street
> Brooklyn, NY 11201
> ```

Comment: It's worth noting that for much of MetroCard history, this was not possible, so people might find outdated information that says as much.

Comment: And it's worth mentioning that this doesn't work for the Metro cards that can be bought at the Air Train station - at any vending machine they allow only to add Money.

Comment: If you are a New Yorker, I think it is better to have both per-per-ride and timed metrocards at the same time in your pocket so that you can use the former for select bus services or airtrain while you continue using the latter for regular subway rides.

Comment: @user5054 What would be the benefit of that, given the quote above suggesting that it's possible to use the dollar-value at locations that don't accept unlimited cards, even though an unlimited pass is currently active? Am I missing something?

Comment: @lxgr I think it helps when you want to take a ride or two that you'd rather not trigger the timer for (that would otherwise be triggered), in case you were saving the time value for a day where you need to ride more frequently (iirc the timer kicks upon first eligible swipe when time is available).

Comment: Ah, not wanting to activate an already loaded unlimited pass is a good point, thanks!